# Swift string as UIColor object

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I am trying to convert the string 'red' to `UIColor.red`, this is what I got so far:

```
let rowColor = row.ResponsibilityColor!

print(rowColor) //this is "red"

styleToApply.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
```

Now if I know if I do this, I will no doubt have an error as `UIColor` does not have a property called `rowColor`:

```
styleToApply.backgroundColor = UIColor.rowColor
```

Is it possible to accomplish what I am trying to do? I dont have to use if conditions, because the color values are coming from a web service.

Comment: What does your API send you for the color you are talking about? A `String` or `HEX Code`? Or something other than that?

Comment: Parse them, store them in a data class and provide `UIColor` variables on that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like that ?

```
extension String {
    func color() -> UIColor? {
        switch(self){
        case "red":
            return UIColor.red
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

**Use it like that :**

```
let rowColor = "red"
let color = rowColor.color()
print(color ?? "color not found in String extensions.")
```

it prints the **red** `UIColor` : 
r 1,0 g 0,0 b 0,0 a 1,0

The inconvenient is that you must have all your API color identifiers declared in the `String extension` to convert it to the right `UIColor`, this solution can be improved.

Comment: The problem with the color method is I dont know all the colors from the API

Comment: You can't get the corresponding `UIColor` if you don't know all the colors, if you received a color such as **"my_wonderfull_color"**, you don't have any possibility to retrieve the corresponding `UIColor` in swift. 

But maybe you have other information to retrieve the `UIColor` such as the hexadecimal code ?

Comment: @user979331 what API are you talking about?  If you mean the ones supplied by 'UIColor' you can look at the documentation.  If you mean the ones that will be used by your app then you need to define them somewhere or how do you know what string is what colour (e.g. "yellow" could return a red colour if you wanted).